# How to get a td-class stored into json file into an html table (using ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

First of all I need to admit that my knowledge of Javascript is very limited. I have been struggling in order to get my page content refreshed in the background without a page refresh using jQuery's AJAX. So far I've managed to get all the content variables that need to be updated succesfully through div's. Now I would also like to change the td class according the value that is within the div. I prefer to store this info into a variabel that I can bring to my html page and I was wondering how I could accomplish that.

Here is simplified example of my code :

**php script that generates the wanted variables and stores (echoes) them into a json array (example.php)**

```
$variable1 = 20;

if ($variable1 > 50) {
$variable1class="positive";
} else {
$variable1class="negative";
}

$array['variable1']      = $variable1;
$array['variable1class'] = $variable1class;

echo json_encode($array);
```

**html table where the variable is retrieved from the json generated by the example.php:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='variable1class'>
        <div id='variable1'></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     refresh();
    });

    function refresh() {
         $.getJSON('example.php', function(data) {
            $('div#variable1').html(data.variable1);
       });
    setTimeout("refresh()",10000);
   }
```

the above code does perfectly refresh the php page in the background and changes the content in de div (variable1) in the html page.

How can I insert the td-class (also stored in the json)? Something like the following would have been great, but obviously didn't work :)

**javascipt:**

```
function refresh() {
             $.getJSON('example.php', function(data) {
                $('div#variable1').html(data.variable1);
                $('td#variable1class').html(data.variable1class);               
             });
    setTimeout("refresh()",10000);
}
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: debug your 'data' variable with console.log and look in your browser for any errors. The syntax you gave should work however unlogical, since you are first setting html of the child of parent A and then setting the html of parent A itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('td.variable1class').addClass(data.variable1class);
```